# Object Classes and Random Variables

Tags: python, object, random

I am writing a Dog class such that each dog object created contains height and weight field variables. Each of these should be initialized randomly for every dog. Height should be initialized to a random float in the range [1.00,100.0]cm. Weight should be initialized randomly in the range [0.7,20]kg. I have this, but it won't output. What am I doing worng

class Dog:
    import random

```
def_init_(self,heihgt,weight):
    self.height = height
    self.weight = weight

    r = random.random()
    a = dog(0.0,101.0)
    b = dog(0.6,21.0)
```

Comment: Well for one, I don't believe that's syntactically-valid Python (def_init_?). Second, what do you mean by "it won't output"? Do you mean that it won't print to the screen? But there are no calls to `print` anywhere...

Comment: despite all things that mentioned @jme, random float random.uniform https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are explicitly setting the height and weight of each dog if you pass it in as parameters like that. If you want to initialize with random values, don't bother with passing in any variables:

```
>>> import random
>>> class dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = random.uniform(1.0,100.0)
        self.weight = random.uniform(.7,20.0)

>>> dog1 = dog()
>>> dog1.height
79.21247401443837
>>> dog1.weight
16.713010614190193
>>> dog2 = dog()
>>> dog2.height
48.90049233226392
```

however, if you want to be allowed to also explicitly state height and weight as needed, you can have default arguments:

```
>>> class dog():
    def __init__(self,height = None, weight = None):
        self.height = height if height else random.uniform(1.0,100.0)
        self.weight = weight if weight else random.uniform(.7,20.0)

>>> dog().height
78.10866941943496
>>> dog().height
50.715307081419276
>>> dog(20).height
20
```

btw if you input `0` as your height or weight, the init will evaluate that as false and so will pick a random float and not set it to 0. I left it like this because I assumed you would never want a dog with 0 height or weight (though one should not discriminate on a dog's appearance).

Comment: If I were to want to write a function called makePack() that takes an integer parameter, n, and returns a list of n Dog objects, would I use a list correct like this? 

for count in makeFlock(n):
    n = Duck()
    n.attr = count
    Duck.append(n)